# Integrating CreditSafe With Sage CRM

Tags: sage-crm

I am looking to integrate Credit Safe with Sage. I tried this test code

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            CreditSafe.GlobalDataServiceClient creditSafe = new CreditSafe.GlobalDataServiceClient();
            CreditSafe.CountriesListingFilter f = new CreditSafe.CountriesListingFilter();
            CreditSafe.CountriesList countries = creditSafe.GetCountries(f);

    }
```

but get the error

> The HTTP request is unathorised with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication Header received form the Server was 'Basic realm="creditsafe.com"

Comment: error is : The HTTP request is unathorised with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication Header received form the Server was  'Basic realm="creditsafe.com"  '

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It was a setting in the config file in case you havent figured this out. Had to setup the config file like so:

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_GlobalDataService" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
      messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

The main part is the security mode section. Hope that helps!